# SQL Server a trigger on each table, reasons for it being bad?

Tags: sql-server

I have joined a team where **ALL** tables have triggers on them. It seems primarily for auditing e.g., who created or updated it and dates.

What I have learnt thus far is that they can be bad and watching Brent Ozar's stuff, this all makes me worry. I've never used them and tended to keep clear of them, setting this data normally in the API side if needs be.

1. Is this equivalent to 2 updates instead of one?
2. Also it seem to update all the columns even if they don't change!? does that look right? What I mean is that if I update a row and set a new Price, will that also trigger a change on the other fields that have not changed, and hence also cause the index to be changed, when nothing changed say on the StartDate.

This all makes me very worried!

Does this mean that if I have any indexes on the table; any update will trigger a change in all of them, as all the columns get changed? and hence cause a knock on issue having to constantly update indexes?

Similar to this example one:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTrigger]
ON [dbo].[MyTable]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF NOT EXISTS (
        -- We have a check here to stop inserting overlapping data
    )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE 
            p
        SET           
            p.MyId = i.MyId,
            p.StartDate = i.StartDate,
            p.EndDate = i.EndDate,
            p.Price = i.Price,              
            p.CreatedBy = i.CreatedBy,
            p.CreatedDate = i.CreatedDate,
            p.AuditUser = CASE WHEN UPDATE(AuditUser) THEN i.AuditUser ELSE SUSER_SNAME() END,
            p.AuditDate = SYSUTCDATETIME(),
            p.AuditApp = RTRIM(ISNULL(APP_NAME(),''))
        FROM 
            PriceValues p
        INNER JOIN
            inserted i ON p.Id = i.Id
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Cant update due to overlap', 16, 101);  
    END
END
```

I'm looking for consensus on what is the best angle of attack if this is going to start biting us. If this is an issue I need details on why and what we can do to remove this issue? Something to go back to the team and business and explain to them.

Comment: The trigger *does join* on the `Inserted` pseudo table - so it will **NOT** update **ALL** rows - really only those that have been updated.

Comment: Ok thanks @marc_s, I put rows instead of columns, thanks for that, updated it with columns now, hopefully that makes more sense?

Comment: `-- We have a check here to stop inserting overlapping data` should just use a unique constraint

Answer (score 1):

Triggers *can* cause problems, but they're not inherently terrible.  Perform normal performance monitoring on the database to determine if there is an issue that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example the trigger is used to inject additional information for the Audit columns.

Being an `instead of` trigger It's a single update of only the intended row(s).

Triggers have the *potential* to be bad for performance and can create problems down the line if you encapsulate business logic in them as they are often overlooked or not tested, plus are a common cause of bugs if not understood correctly, or for example where ported from another RDBMS where the operation is similar but not identical to SQL Server.

In your case the trigger is as it should be, short and sweet. However, there could be a performance hit from the `if not exists` part which you've chosen to withold - generally to know if something does *not* exist SQL Server must scan the narrowest supporting index it has available, which might impact on concurrency among other things.

Comment: Thanks @Stu, yea I didnt want to divulge the if not exists stuff, but that makes sense. Sound like its not as bad as I thought, I'm still not keen on them though, lol

Comment: there's no right or wrong answer, it's the needs of the business; if you want to capture the application name or other session-related metadata it's the most reliable way as it caters for data modification operations from all connecting applications and ad-hoc updates.